# AWS Cloudwatch alarm for each single instance of an auto scaling group

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling, amazon-cloudwatch

We have configured an Auto Scaling group in AWS. And it works fine. We have configured some alarms for the group, such as: send alarm if the average CPUUtilization > 60 for 2 minutes ... use AWS CLI.

The only problem is, if we want to monitoring each instance in the group. We have to configure them manually. Are they any way to do it automatically like config, template?

Comment: What is your use-case for requiring an alarm on each instance individually?

Answer (score 7):

Amazon CloudWatch alarms can be created on the **Auto Scaling group** as a whole, such as `Average CPUUtilization`. This is because alarms are used to tell Auto Scaling when to add/remove instances and such decisions would be based upon the group as a whole. For example, if one machine is 100% busy but another is 0% busy, then **on average** the group is only 50% busy.

There should be no reason for placing an alarm on the individual instances in an auto-scaling group, at least as far as triggering a scaling action.

There is no in-built capability to specify an alarm that will be applied against each auto-scaled instance individually. You could do it programmatically by **responding to an Amazon SNS notification** whenever an instance is added/removed by Auto Scaling, but this would require your own code to be written.

Comment: thanks for your answer. just like your example, we have two instances, one is 100% busy, another is 0% busy. our load balancer are using round robin, and about 50% of our traffics will still be directed to instance 1, which is overloaded.

So we want to avoid this case, and make some alarms on each instance.

Comment: Are your requests so resource-intensive that they consume a large portion of CPU or a long period of time? If so, you might be better-off queuing requests via SQS for back-end processing rather than having the end-user wait for a long period of time. If you requests are relatively short (eg max 5-10 seconds), they will balance out between the servers on average.

Comment: This is exactly what i'm trying to find out. If i have one host with an issue (e.g. stuck on high cpu) i would like to get an alert although avg. is ok

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish this with lifecycle hooks and a little lambda glue. When you have lifecycle events for adding or terminating an instance, you can create an alarm on that individual instance or remove it (depending on the event) via a lambda function.

To John's point, this is a little bit of an anti-pattern with horizontal scaling and load balancing. However, theory and practice sometimes diverge.